# Cant install gsap normal version

Tags: gsap

i'm trying to download zip and install the normall version with npm but, in the information it says Put the gsap-bonus.tgz file (found in the npm-install-this directory) in the root directory of your project.
but theres no npm install-this directory in the zip that i download, what should i do?

i'm trying to download zip and install the normall version with npm but, in the information it says Put the gsap-bonus.tgz file (found in the npm-install-this directory) in the root directory of your project.
but theres no npm install-this directory in the zip that i download, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue and googled this and found your question.

Basically, what I did I is just registered and downloaded the zip after that, and then I received `npm-install-this` folder

Answer (score 0):

To supplement on the answer of Marko, downloaded the 'gsap club' zip file and unzip it inside your project.

Then you can run `npm install src/gsap/npm-install-this/gsap-bonus.tgz`. Make sure that the path in your command is correct.